# Separating Child Nodes using java XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

How should I separate the "Student" node which contains only "email" tag. The below xml contains various child nodes like name, class, address and email within Student tag. But one student tag contains only "email". How should i separate only that particular Student tag alone using java XML. Please help, I am new to Java XML.

```
<Student>
    <name>Sample1</name>
    <class>1</class>
    <address>2525</address>
    <email>sample1@sample.com</email>
</Student>

<Student>
    <name>Sample2</name>
    <class>2</class>
    <address>2153</address>
    <email>sample2@sample.com</email>
</Student>

<Student>
    <email>sample3@sample.com</email>
</Student>
```

Comment: Take all Students, go through all of them and if one has no name, no class and no address then it's that student.

Comment: @Arun. I have created a sample example for demonstration sufficing your requirement. let me know in case you need more details

Comment: @mhasan. Thanks a lot..!! Now I got what I exactly want...

Comment: Please accept the solution and mark as +1

Answer (score 0):

XPath expression to select only Student nodes that contain no name, class and address child nodes. '/Student[not(name) and not(class) and not(address)]'. Not quite sure what exactly your constraints and requirements are but this expression will work in your example. For a simple code example for Java there are many good tutorials, e.g.: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_xpath_parse_document.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

    public class Parser {

        private static String XPATH_EXPRESSION_STRING = "//Students/Student[not ((name) and (class)  and (address))]";
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder;
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = builder.parse("C:\\Users\\NPGM81B\\Desktop\\Students.xml");

                // Create XPathFactory object
                XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

                // Create XPath object
                XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
                XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(XPATH_EXPRESSION_STRING);
                Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodes.item(i);
                    printNode(node, "********");
                }
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        private static void printNode(Node rootNode, String spacer) {
            System.out.println(spacer + rootNode.getNodeName() + " -> " + rootNode.getNodeValue());
            NodeList nl = rootNode.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
                printNode(nl.item(i), spacer + "   ");
        }

    }

Sample XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Students>
   <Student>
      <name>Sample1</name>
      <class>1</class>
      <address>2525</address>
      <email>sample1@sample.com</email>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <name>Sample2</name>
      <class>2</class>
      <address>2153</address>
      <email>sample2@sample.com</email>
   </Student>
   <Student>
      <email>sample3@sample.com</email>
   </Student>
</Students>
```